# Angular-Strap Tooltip Showing Empty Tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip, angular-strap

I am using angular-strap tooltips, and when I hover over the input, it comes up with an empty tooltip, but I would like none to come up (until I define a title for it!)

[image]

Here is my tooltip definition:

```
<input placeholder="Choose a username" type="text" class="form-control"
    ng-model="regData.username" 
    data-animation="am-flip-x" data-html="true" 
    bs-tooltip="usernameTooltip" data-placement="right"
    tabindex=1>
```

I have tried setting data-bs-show="false", data-bs-enabled="false" and defined $scope.usernameTooltip = { title: null }, and none of those have stopped it from appearing. Should I define $scope.usernameTooltip in a different way?

Comment: If you don't want a tooltip... why don't you just get rid of the `bs-tooltip="usernameTooltip"`?

Comment: I do want that tooltip. I just don't want it to show when I have not defined a title for it yet.

Comment: It looks like it works exactly how you expect, I think there is something else in your code: http://jsfiddle.net/uvsoskc9/1/

Comment: Set a manual trigger.